# how to expand all items on FAQ list?

Tags: jquery

I have made a FAQ slide toggle list, and I want to expand all items when I click "show all" button.

```
<a href="#" class="btnShowAll">show all</a>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.faqList dd').hide();
    $('.faqList dt').hover(function(){$(this).addClass('hover')},function(){$(this).removeClass('hover')}).click(function(){
      $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');
    });
});  

<div class="faqList">
  <dl>
   <dt>question1</dt>
   <dd>Answer1</dd>
   <dt>question2</dt>
   <dd>Answer2</dd>
  </dl> 
</div>
```

How do I do that event ? please help~

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding what you want to do correctly, I think you've severly over complicated it. Just use the .slideToggle function:

```
.faqList {
   display: none;
}


$(function() {

  $( ".btnShowAll" ).click(function() {
    $( ".faqList" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
    });
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qRts9/6/